# Can you solve this venn diagram problem and explain how you did it?

Tags: statistics

How many numbers between 1 and 1200 are not multiples of 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
How many numbers between 1 and 1200 are a multiple of 2? And how many numbers between 1 and 1200 are a multiple of 3? What does it mean to be a multiple of both 2 and 3? Now try to draw a Venn diagram of this situation.